# one textbox one button two different pages in html

Tags: html, button, textbox, action

i am trying to assign a textbox value to a php variable now problem is i want one button to work for two different pages i.e if i enter in a text box 'a'and click on button it should redirect to 'a.php' page if i write in a text box 'b' it should redirect to 'b.php'.

so one textbox,one button two different pages.

Code :

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script>
function submitForm(action)
{
    document.getElementById('a').action = action;
    document.getElementById('a').submit();
}
function submitForm1(action)
{
    document.getElementById('b').action = action;
    document.getElementById('b').submit();
}

</script>
</head>
 <body >



<h3><font face="verdana" size="3"><b>Enter Text:</b></h3>

 <input type="text"  align="right" style="font-size:15pt;height:32px;"><br><br>

    <form action="b.php" name="b" id="b" method="post"> 
<form action="a.php" name="a" id="a" method="post">

 <input type="submit" onclick="submitForm('a.php')" value="TRY"  name="a">
 <input type="button" onclick="submitForm1('b.php')" value="TRY" name="b">



    </form>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the action onsubmit based on the text inside the input.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onsubmit_handler(){
            var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
            var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
            if(data == "a")
                myForm.setAttribute('action', 'a.php');
            else if(data == "b")
                myForm.setAttribute('action', 'b.php');
            else
                myForm.setAttribute('action', 'error.php');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Enter Text:</h3>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="onsubmit_handler()">
        <input type="text" id="data" name="data" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test code here : http://jsfiddle.net/Eg9S4/

Comment: Thank you so much it works but can you please tell me how am i going to assigh this value to php variable as i have tried belowed code but this is not working.                                                              CODE :                                                                        $q=$_POST['data'];

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to be that you're using getElementById but the input elements don't have an ID (they only have a name).

<strike>I'd also recommend attaching an onSubmit event to the form and removing the onClick events from the buttons.</strike>

Edit: After looking at the code in detail I saw that there were some other issues that were probably hindering the  opersation.  The most notable one was that you can't nest form tags.  There were some other CSS and validation issues.

Here is some working code:

Test Page

```
    function SubmitForm(el) {

        // Get the form element so that we can set the action later
        var form = document.getElementById('theForm');


        // Set the action for the form based on which button was clicked
        if (el.id == "A")
            form.action = "a.php";

        if (el.id == "B")
            form.action = "b.php";

        // You dont need to submit the form. It's alreasdy happening, so there is no need for an explicit call.
    }

</script>
```

```
<h3 style="font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold;">Enter Text:</h3>

<input type="text" style="font-size:15pt;height:32px;"><br><br>

<form method="post" onsubmit="SubmitForm();" action="fake.html" id="theForm">
    <input type="submit" id="A" value="A" onclick="SubmitForm(this);">
    <input type="submit" id="B" value="B" onclick="SubmitForm(this);">
</form>
```

Comment: Ah. I was going down the "two submit buttons" route and didn't realize you wanted one textbox and one button.  If that's the case, use Thanasis' code above!

Comment: Thank you so much it works but can you please tell me how am i going to assigh this value to php variable as i have tried but this is not working.                                                              CODE :                                                                        $q='$_POST['data']';

Comment: My previous answer didn't have an ID for the input, but assuming it was `firstName` then the PHP code would be `$q=$_POST["firstName"];`

Comment: What is it doing or not doing? Are you getting an error?

Comment: i just changed my browser and it worked thank you guys ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

use this codes buddy

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script>
function submitForm()
{
    var link=document.getElementById('a');
var str1 = "a.php";
var n = str1.localeCompare(link);

if(n==1)
{
    window.open("main.html");

}

else if(n==-1)
{
    window.open("index.html");
}
} 



</script>
</head>
<body >



<h3><font face="verdana" size="3"><b>Enter Text:</b></h3>

<input type="text"  align="right" style="font-size:15pt;height:32px;"><br><br>


<input type="submit" onclick="submitForm()" value="TRY"  name="a">





</form>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That wont submit the form data.