# How use Dynamic hyperlink on each wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, wordpress-theming

I built a static button from backend but i want that button get hyperlink from post editor

I have designed a static design and button  on singlepost.php file now i want that when i create a new post then i want to put a redirect hyperlink behind that button from post editor section. how can i do that ?

how i set hyperlink behind that "Get Deal" button from post page ?

Get Deal button is static for all post but this button take link when i put from post editor section (so there will be separate dynamic link for each post)

My static design code for post is :

```
<div class="price_row_grid">
    <div class="price_for_grid floatleft">
        <?php theme_create_btn('no', 'price'); ?>

    </div>

    <div class="floatright vendor_for_grid">
        <?php if ($price_meta == 'admin'): ?>
            <?php $author_id = $post->post_author; ?>
            <a class="admin" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($author_id) ?>" title="<?php the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); ?>">
                <?php echo get_avatar($author_id, '22'); ?>
            </a>
        <?php elseif ($price_meta == 'store'): ?>
            <div class="brand_logo_small">
                <?php WPSM_Postfilters::re_show_brand_tax('logo'); //show brand logo?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>


 <div class="price_row_grid">
        <div class="price_for_grid floatleft">
            <p class="button">Get Deal</p>



        </div>
```

Now how i set hyperlink behind "Get Deal" from post editor because i just build button which is static for all pages but i want to set different hyperlink for each page.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a help from this example

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function onsubmit_handler(){
        var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
        var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
        if(data == "a")
            myForm.setAttribute('action', 'a.php');
        else if(data == "b")
            myForm.setAttribute('action', 'b.php');
        else
            myForm.setAttribute('action', 'error.php');
    }
    </script>
    </head>
     <body>
    <h3>Enter Text:</h3>
   <form id="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="onsubmit_handler()">
    <input type="text" id="data" name="data" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: refrence link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455274/one-textbox-one-button-two-different-pages-in-html